# how to bootstrap ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys.

I have an error.

The next message appears when i type `source ~/ros/setup.bash`  in the command line:

"rospack could not be found, you cannot have rosbash features until you bootstrap ros"

How can i fix this? By the way, i'm using slackware 14.0

Greetings

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/79251/how-to-bootstrap-ros?/) by [Bernard_o](https://answers.ros.org/users/6446/bernard_o/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-09-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-09-14**:
What version of ROS are you installing? What instructions are you following.  The recommended install from source is here: http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Source

**Comment by [Bernard_o](https://answers.ros.org/users/6446/bernard_o/) on 2013-09-14**:
Hi. Thanks for answering, i'm tryiing to install groovy. I followed the instructions of this page: http://ftp.isr.ist.utl.pt/pub/roswiki/diamondback(2f)Installation(2f)Slackware.html
But no luck when i type "source ~/ros/setup.bash" in the command line.

**Comment by [Bernard_o](https://answers.ros.org/users/6446/bernard_o/) on 2013-09-14**:
Forgot to mention that i selected the ful desktop install with this command:
rosinstall -n ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=groovy&variant=desktop&overlay=no"
before typing "source ~/ros/setup.bash"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're following a diamondback tutorial but trying to install Groovy.  I suggest you follow the Ubuntu Source installation page: http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/Source You will need to substitute all the system dependency commands for slackware.

If you'd like to contribute your efforts to adapt the Ubuntu Source installation into a new version of the Slackware instructions I'm sure that would be appreciated.

You might be able to get diamondback to run from the old URL but diamondback is very old and has not been supported for close to a year, not all sources may still be available.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0